# Android Vuforia Live Texture on 3d Model Coloring App

Tags: android, texture-mapping, vuforia

thanks in advance for any help that could be provided.
I would like to know if anyone can suggest or point to the right direction of researching and developing an app that will allow the client to color in an black a white coloring book and have vuforia map the texture that the client just painted into a 3d model. I have this youtube video as example to what I would like to achieve.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWzurBQ81CM
I am trying to find out if vuforia is capable to recreate this or which SDK I should be looking into to be able to have the client color in the drawing and use the client's coloring as a texture, It does not have to be synthesized from the paper, the coloring app could exist on the device.
Thanks in advance.  I am not sure as to where to start researching this, so I am looking for direction, tutorials, books, or any kind of research material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably RegionCapture is what you are looking for.

This package can be implemented with Vuforia and allows you creating Coloring Apps in Augmented Reality using Unity 3D.

[RegionCapture Vuforia Unity](https://github.com/maximrouf/RegionCapture)

In addition to this, you can find a tutorial on youtube with the installation procedure.

[Coloring App Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54W5hF-ZnO8)

I hope this information is helpful to you.

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

Unity 3d and Vuforia can be used to get the desirable output like this.

Comment: any research content or tutorial you could recommend?

Comment: If you have any knowledge about Unity then here is the tutorial :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfxqfdtxyVA